# How to split a string with a comma as delimiter to a string that looks like an array with string elements?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need a string like: `"one, two, thee, four"`
to be changed into string like: `"["one", "two", "three", "four"]"`

So, I've been trying to come up with a solution that tackles most use-cases, but without success.
So far I came up with the following:

```
 var splitString = <mystring>.split(', ');
 var stringWithQuotes = `"` + stringSplit.join(`", "`) + `"`;
```

Though an input such as `"one,two,thee,four"` (without spaces) in between won't split the string into parts. The square brackets are missing aswell.

Any ideas?

Comment: _"I need a string like: `"one, two, thee, four"`"_ - then why should it also work with `"one,two,thee,four"`? If both should work split on the comma and trim the space on each element.

Comment: Seems odd... but `JSON.stringify("one, two, thee, four".split(", "))`

Comment: @epascarello That doesn't include spaces after each comma.

Comment: @iota whitespace is meaningless.... if they really matter a stringify formatter can add it. I honestly think the question is a bandaid for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on a regular expression to allow optional whitespace between tokens.

```js
let str = "one,two,thee,four";
let parts = str.split(/,\s*/);
let res = '["' + parts.join('", "') + '"]';
console.log(res);
```

Comment: How `["one", "two", "thee", "four"]` same as `"["one", "two", "three", "four"]"`

Comment: @decpk I interpreted the outer double quotes as the delimiters for the string.

Comment: Those were indeed the delimiters, nice usage of the regex part there. Seems like what I was needing, thanks!

Comment: @Krelis Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```js
    var mystr = "one, two, thee, four";
    var myarr = mystr.split(", ");
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myarr);
    console.log(myJSON);
```

Return the string '["one", "two", "three", "four"]'

Comment: This actually returns "["one"," two"," thee"," four"]" -- you need to strip spaces off of each element.